# Toque Duplo Abre duas Activitys Android

Tags: android, touch

Estou com um problema em uma lista em que uso um `RecyclerView`, ao clicar em um item da lista, o `OnClickListener` é tratado no `ViewHolder` desse `RecyclerView`:
MeuViewHolder:

```
public ClientesViewHolder(Context ctx, View itemView, Activity act) {
   super(itemView);
   itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent it = new Intent(ctx, TelaDadosClientes.class);
    Bundle animacao = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, it, animacao);
 }
```

Ao clicar em um item da lista é aberto uma nova `activity` com uma animação(que não vem ao caso).
 O meu problema é que se eu clicar duas vezes em um item da lista ele abre duas vezes a mesma `activity`. Tem como eu desativar esse toque duplo (algo como OnDoubleClickListener return false)?

**OBS:** Caso não tenha entendido comente que darei mais detalhes se necessário.

Comment: desconheço o seu procedimento, mas para evitar que uma activity abra novamente na tela eu uso `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

espero que ajude

Comment: Olá @Armando não funcionou, continua abrindo duas activitys se eu clicar duas vezes em um item.

Comment: E `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema criando uma função estática parecida com um timer:

Utils.java

```
private static int clk = 0;

public static boolean testClique(int ms) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
          clk = 0; 
        }
    };

    if (clk == 0) {
        clk = 1;
        handler.postDelayed(r, ms);
        return true;
    }
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    return false;
}
```

Assim eu posso chamar ela em qualquer lugar que eu não queira que seja executada uma mesma ação duas vezes caso seja dado um duplo clique exemplo:

```
// Esse era meu problema ao dar dois toques rápidos em um item do recyclerView
// ele abria duas vezes a mesma activity

if (Utils.testClique(1000)) { // Envio um intervalo de 1s para poder clicar de novo
     Intent it = new Intent(contexto, MinhaActivity.class);
     Bundle animacao = ActivityOptionsCompat...;
     ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, it, animacao);
}
// Também uso esta função em Buttons, Toolbar Itens, e onde mais eu quiser
```

Agora quando clico em uma `view` ele dá um timer (usando o tempo que eu definir) até poder realizar uma ação novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a lógica de Bruno existe uma maneira alternativa de evitar o duplo click também. Crie uma variável do tipo long no seu adapter

- private long mLastClickTime = 0;

E no método onClick do item em seu adapter você verifica o tempo do click , se está respeitando um intervalo de 1000 milissegundos ou o tempo definido por você

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    //verifique se o tempo do último click tem um intervalo de 1000 milessegundos
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000)
    {
        return;
    }

    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo 
no meu caso abaixo e uso um listview e pego o item selecionado da seguinte forma..

ltsunidades.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int posicao, long id) {
                Tab_UC obj = (Tab_UC) adapter.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
                String filial = "" + obj.getCod_UC();
                Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Empresa.class);
                it.putExtra("Filial", filial);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });
```

não sei se desta forma ira funcionar no RecyclerView.. porem no meu caso o duplo clique nem funciona.. 
espero ter ajudado..

Comment: Na verdade (logicamente falando) o seu código não está fazendo nada de diferente do meu. Não vejo como isso pode me ajudar.

Comment: ta sim   muda quando vc chama o onclick    no meu caso  é onitemclick  de uma olhada la

Comment: O onItemClick() não funciona no RecyclerView. E se eu fosse usar seu código, eu tiraria as duas primeiras linhas do onItemClick() e só usaria a Intent para abrir minha Activity, coisa que eu já faço mas usando uma animação.

Comment: sim sim  eu nunca usei o RecyclerView   desculpe não poder ajudar então =(

Comment: Pelo menos tentou, eu só não consigo acreditar que ninguém passou por isso kkk, tipo até em um Button se eu der dois toques rapidos ele abre duas Activitys !!